# SL Exit Problems in my Inside Candle Strategy

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, tradingview-api

Sometimes It exits very accurately,

sometimes It get didn't get exitted on time,

sometimes It get exiited very incorrectly

and sometimes It get exitted at the same time of entry.

I am very much frustrated seeing this.

I have also plotted the SL horizontal line in the code but still can't solve the issue and hence frustrated very much.

It is a intraday strategy on 15min timeframe.

Please Help !!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Inside Candle ", overlay=true,slippage = 3,commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,commission_value = 0.05,initial_capital = 10000,calc_on_order_fills = true,calc_on_every_tick = true,pyramiding = 1000,backtest_fill_limits_assumption = 2,close_entries_rule = "FIFO")

//=============================================Entry and exit Timings (9:30 a.m. to 2:30 p.m.)===========================================================

string sessionInput = input.session("0915-1415", "Session")
string daysInput = input.string("1234567", tooltip = "1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday")
sessionString = sessionInput + ":" + daysInput
inSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionString))
bgcolor(inSession ? color.rgb(178, 181, 190, 96) : na)

//================================================Detecting Inside Candle and ema===========================================================

//Defining Inside Candle and 50ema

ema = ta.ema(close,150)
plot(ema,"ema",color.orange,linewidth = 2)

IC = (high <= high[1] and low >= low[1])

//==================================================Defining Entry Conditions=====================================================================================================

//LONG above 50ema and SHORT below 50ema

ICwithemaLONG = IC and (close > ema) 
ICwithemaSHORT = IC and (close < ema) 

//Previous Candle is an Inside Candle = IC[1] and // High of current candle is greater than previous (Inside) candle = high > high[1] 
//and close of previous(Inside) candle > ema = close[1] > ema then ====>>>>>> LONG

EntryCandleLONG = IC[1] and (high[0] > high[1]) and (close[1] > ema)
EntryCandleSHORT = IC[1] and (low[0] < low[1]) and (close[1] < ema) 

//================================================Detecting Inside Candle high and low====================================================================

//Detecting Inside Candle High and Low

h = high + (1 * syminfo.mintick)
l = low - (1 * syminfo.mintick)

var float IC_high = na
var float IC_low = na

var float IC_high1 = na
var float IC_low1 = na

//Getting high and low to the Inside Candle previous to Entry Candle 

if (EntryCandleLONG == true)
    IC_high := high[1]
    IC_low := low[1]

if (EntryCandleSHORT == true)  
    IC_high1 := high[1]
    IC_low1 := low[1]  

LONG_SL = IC_low - (1 * syminfo.mintick)
SHORT_SL = IC_high1 + (1 * syminfo.mintick)

plot(LONG_SL,color = color.red,linewidth = 2)
plot(SHORT_SL,color = color.green,linewidth = 2)

//======================================================================Coloring Bars===========================================

barcolor(ICwithemaLONG ? color.white : na)
barcolor(ICwithemaSHORT ? color.white : na)
barcolor(EntryCandleLONG ? color.yellow : na)
barcolor(EntryCandleSHORT ? color.yellow : na)

//=====================================================================Money Management==========================================================================================

initial_capital = input(defval = 10000 , title = "initial capital")
percentRisk = input(defval = 0.01,title = "Risk per trade")

LONG_Position_Size = ((initial_capital * percentRisk) / (h - l))
SHORT_Position_Size = ((initial_capital * percentRisk) / (h - l))

//=============================================================Entry restricted to only next 1 bar================================================================================================================

is_long = strategy.position_size > 0
cancel_long_order = barstate.isconfirmed and ICwithemaLONG[1] and not is_long

is_short = strategy.position_size > 0
cancel_short_order = barstate.isconfirmed and ICwithemaSHORT[1] and not is_short 

//==============================================LONG Entry and Exit Conditions==========================================================================

if (ICwithemaLONG and inSession)
    strategy.entry("LONG",strategy.long,stop =  h,qty = LONG_Position_Size)
 
    stoploss = LONG_SL
    target = h + ((h-l)*3)  

    strategy.exit("LONG Exit",from_entry = "LONG",stop = stoploss,limit = target)  

if (cancel_long_order)        
    strategy.cancel("LONG")

//Exiting trade at 3:15 p.m.     

if (hour==15 and minute==00)
    strategy.close_all("Day Close" )

//==============================================SHORT Entry and Exit Conditions==========================================================================

if (ICwithemaSHORT and inSession) 
    strategy.entry("SHORT",strategy.short,stop =  l,qty = SHORT_Position_Size)

    STOPLOSS = SHORT_SL
    TARGET = l - ((h-l) * 3)

    strategy.exit("SHORT SL",from_entry="SHORT",stop = STOPLOSS,limit = TARGET)

//Only taking entry on next candle of inside candle and avoid entries in later candles   

if (cancel_short_order)
    strategy.cancel("SHORT")

//Exiting trade at 3:15 p.m.    

if (hour==15 and minute==00)
    strategy.close_all("Day Close")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not place your exit order conditionally. If you want to exit based on some conditions, you should use `strategy.close()`.

```
if (ICwithemaLONG and inSession)
    strategy.entry("LONG",strategy.long,stop =  h,qty = LONG_Position_Size)
 
    stoploss = LONG_SL
    target = h + ((h-l)*3)  

    strategy.exit("LONG Exit",from_entry = "LONG",stop = stoploss,limit = target)
```

You see, whenever `(ICwithemaLONG and inSession)` is `true`, you will enter this if block and modify the exit order with the new `stoploss` and `target` prices.

What you need to do is, use `var` variables for your take profit and stop loss and update them once you enter a trade. You need to make them `var` so that their values do not change between new executions.

Then place your exit order if you are in a long position.

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("LONG Exit",from_entry = "LONG",stop = stoploss,limit = target)
```

Comment: I am not able to do it even after your opinions.Can you please write the code of the which I have to make changes in my strategy.